# Anything other than

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

What the phrase "can be anything other than" in the given sentence means i.e. how can it be interpreted in any sentence or how it affects on any sentence or what is the overal meaning of the sentence?

> It is doubtful whether an investor's snipping at management can ever be anything other than counterproductive.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're looking for. By "role", do you mean parts of speech, rhetoric, intent, or something else?

Comment: I presume there’s a typo and the original used the verb *sniping*.

Answer (score 1):

In the given context: *can be anything other than* =~ *can be different from* (what is called 'counterproductive'). In other words:

> Unlikely an investor's snipping at management can be qualified with
>   another adjective, different from 'counterproductive'.

Answer (score 1):

***Cannot be anything other than*** is another way of saying ***can only be** (x and nothing else)*. So your sentence says:

> It is ***most likely that*** an investor's snipping at management can ***only*** be counterproductive.

It cannot possess any other quality but this one.